# firestore simple way to get one field in a document by function

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to return one field in a document. Is there a simple way to do this?  This seems overkill:

```
let p = await (await this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`).get().toPromise()).data()!.photoURL;

let p = await this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`).ref.get().then((m) => { return m.data()!.photoURL; });
```

I was thinking something like this, but obviously it doesn't work:

```
let p = await this.afs.doc(`users/${uid}`).get('photoURL);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be all that's needed:

```
let p = await (firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${uid}`).get()).get('photoURL');
```

The `await (firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${uid}`).get())` awaits for the document to be loaded, and then then `get('photoURL')` gets the field.

Comment: This does not work. "Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Observable<DocumentSnapshot>'" referring to the second get()

Comment: Ah, I missed that you're using angularfire2. I rewrite the code to use the JavaScript SDK directly, which makes it much easier to parse (for me at least).

Comment: That does not work.  I am importing firestore in my code using 'private afs: AngularFirestore,', so it is still the same code you had.

Comment: I got it to work with this: ```let p = await (await (this.afs.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).get())).get('photoURL');```